# string::find() me da un error que no comprendo ¿Alguien podría explicarlo?

Tags: string, c++11, búsquedas

He hecho esta función para eliminar parte del nombre de un archivo

```
///remueve una subcadena de una cadena mas grande
string removeSubstring(string mainString, string toRemove)
{
    unsigned int pos = mainString.find(toRemove);

    if(pos!=std::string::npos)
    {
        cout << "pos="<<pos<<" size="<< toRemove.size()<< " toRemove="<< toRemove<< " mainString="<<mainString<< " std::string::npos="<< std::string::npos<<endl;
        mainString.erase(pos,toRemove.size());
    }

    return mainString;///No encontrado retornamos sin modificar
}
```

La función me da este error

```
pos=4294967295 size=12 toRemove=abcdefghijkm mainString=''pepe_coco_liso'' std::string::npos=18446744073709551615
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 4294967294) > this->size() (which is 18)

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Ni ídea de que puede estar fallando. No comprendo nada, lo único que sé es **std::string::find()** está fallando, me está devolviendo un número menor a **std::string::npos** pero a la vez exageradamente enorme. Es decir:

```
pos < std::string::npos
```

o lo que es lo mismo

```
4294967295 < 18446744073709551615
```

Cuando debería ser igual pues le estoy dando un string que no está contenido en el nombre del archivo.

```
//ESTO FUNCIONA
string fileName ="pepe_coco_liso.txt";
fileName = removeSubstring(fileName,"coco");
cout<<fileName<<endl;


///ESTO FALLA
fileName ="pepe_coco_liso.txt";
fileName = removeSubstring(fileName,"abcdefghijkm");
cout<<fileName<<endl;
return 0;
```

¿Alguien le encuentra una explicación de por qué string::find() está fallando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he puesto así y ha funcionado:

```
string removeSubstring(string mainString, string toRemove)
{
    size_t pos=0;

    if((pos = mainString.find(toRemove))!=std::string::npos)
    mainString.erase(pos,toRemove.size());    

    return mainString;///No encontrado retornamos sin modificar
}
```

Por lo visto el error está relacionado con el tipo que usaba, al parecer se debe usar **size_t** y no **unsigned int**, lo raro es que en la documentación dice que **size_t** y **unsigned int** son la misma cosa.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

```
Return Value
The position of the first character of the first match.
If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.

size_t is an unsigned integral type (the same as member type string::size_type)
```

Así que o la documentación se equivoca, o algo raro está pasando. 
Si alguen sabe el verdadero motivo que por favor lo diga.

Comment: `size_t` es un alias... en 32 bits es equivalente a `unsigned int`, pero en 64 bits es equivalente a `unsigned long long`. La documentación te está diciendo que `size_t` es un tipo integral sin signo... y nota que *integral* no es lo mismo que *integer*

Comment: Ahora le veo una razón de ser al tipo **size_t**, antes no comprendia el porque llamar de diferente forma a un tipo que ya existia. Pero claro, es por compatibilidad/portabilidad entre sistemas de 32 y 64 bits. Muchas gracias por la explicación @efeiron.